# Bugzilla through an apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, bugzilla

I am trying to access bugzilla through an apache reverse proxy. I have the usual ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse settings and this works to bring back the page, but it does not bring back any formating, style or graphics.

I have tried to ensure that http compression is turned off for the site. This did not help. Has anyone done this? Will I need to use mod-rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this setup http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies.
It worked for me.
HTH

Comment: Just a comment for others who may have the same issue. On Ubuntu Lucid proxy-html does not enable with ProxyHTMLEnable on as per the documentation. Instead use "SetOutputFilter proxy-html".

Answer (score 0):

Below is the configuration of Bugzilla in Proxy Mode in Apache for Centos7:
Note: this configuration is for domain that is public ally accessible on Port 80

1. Edit Apache configuration file /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
2. Enter below in Virutalhost configuration of your domain e.g example.com

   ProxyRequests off

   ProxyPreserveHost On

   ProxyPass /bugzilla/ http://your_public_server_IP:8080/

   ProxyPassReverse /bugzilla/ http://example.com/bugzilla/
3. Save and restart apache service.

Now you will be access bugzilla using following URL in proxy mode

Bugzilla URL:   http://your_server_ip:8080
Domain URL:     http://example.com/bugzilla/

Thanking You!

Note: Bugzilla is running on port 8080

Please update if any one use above configuration